# Read data frames from a function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

The following two lines will read a data frame, and assign column names:

```
br <-
read.table("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/dat/br.dat")

colnames(br) <- paste(lapply(read.table("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/def/br.def", skip=2, nrows=1), as.character, sep=","))
```

I would like to create a function that reads the file and assigns column names based on the file name, "br" in this case. I have tried:

```
poe4read <- function(x) {
x <- read.table(gsub("x", "br",    "http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/dat/x.dat"))
colnames(x) = paste(lapply(read.table(gsub("x", "br",    "http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/def/x.def"),
                                   skip=2, nrows=1), as.character, sep=","))}
```

This does not return a data frame "br", but it works line by line, creating the data frame "x". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

```
poe4read <- function(x) {
  x <- read.table(paste0("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/dat/",x,".dat")))
  colnames(x) = paste(lapply(read.table(paste0("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/def/",x,".def")), skip=2, nrows=1), as.character, sep=","))}

br <- poe4read("br")
```

Variable are scoped, creating a global variable within a function sounds a bad idea but if you really want to you can do it like this:

```
a <- function(var) {
  assign( var, data.frame(c(1,0)), envir=.GlobalEnv) # Warning this will always create the variable in the gloabl environment
  assign( var, setNames( get(var), "test"), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

We have to use `setNames` which return the modified object instead of modifying it directly inside another `assign` to work on the global variable.

Call

```
> a("mytest")
```

Output:

```
> mytest
  test
1    1
2    0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, this should do the job :

```
poe4read <- function(x){
        fileName <- as.character(x)
        url01 <- paste0("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/dat/", 
                        fileName, ".dat")
        url02 <- paste0("http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/def/", 
                        fileName, ".def")
        x <- read.table(url01, header=FALSE)

        # fetch colnames in the second file
        # and modify column names according to the file name :
        colnames(x) <- paste0(fileName, 
                              paste(lapply(read.table(url02, skip=2, nrows=1),
                              as.character, sep=",")))
        x
      }
```

Result :

```
br <- poe4read("br")
head(br,3)

  brprice brsqft brBedrooms brBaths brAge brOccupancy brPool brStyle 
1   66500    741          1       1    18           1      1       1 
2   66000    741          1       1    18           2      1       1 
3   68500    790          1       1    18           1      0       1 
  brFireplace brWaterfront brDOM 
1           1            0     6 
2           0            0    23 
3           1            0     8
```

When you're calling the function, you need to use quotes around the file name for it to work. `poe4read("br")`.

You should then be able to use it on multiple file adding the name of the specific file at the beginning of each column.